# Assign one allocated pointer to another allocated pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Is the memory that `t2` points to still reachable after the assignment?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double *t1 = (double *)calloc(6, sizeof(double));
  double *t2 = (double *)calloc(6, sizeof(double));
  
  t2=t1;

  free(t1);

  return 0;
}
```

Is the above code recommended? Will it cost memory leak? Or, does the memory `t2` points to just align with what `t1` points to in this case?

Should I just simply use `double *t3 = t1` instead?

Comment: No it is not reachable, no it is not recommended, yes it will cause a memory leak. `double *t3 = t1` yes if you are just trying to have another pointer to the same thing.

Comment: And no, there is no guarantee that the space originally allocated to `t2` is adjacent to, let alone contiguous with, the space allocated to `t1`.  There is no way that `free(t1)` will 'accidentally' (or 'beneficially') free the space that was originally allocated to `t2`.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for your clarification. I was confused for a while as I cannot even `free(t2)` after `free(t1)`. Somehow, I felt the allocated memories just aligned together. Apparently, they are not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your confirmation on free(t1) won't do anything with `t2`.

Comment: " felt the allocated memories just aligned together." What exactly did you mean by this?

Comment: "I cannot even `free(t2)` after `free(t1)`" Indeed, because they both point to the same memory. `free(t2)` freed it properly, then `free(t1)` is a double-free error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the memory that t2 points to still reachable after the assignment?

No

> Is the above code recommended?

No.

> Will it cost memory leak?

Yes, the memory pointed to by `t2` is leaked.

> Or, does the memory t2 points to just align with what t1 points to in this case?

It does but the original `calloc` memory is lost.

> Should I just simply use `double *t3 = t1` instead?

Yes if you just want another pointer variable to the same address.

Comment: "the memory pointed to by `t2` is leaked".  Not quite; the memory that `t2` pointed to before the assignment `t2 = t1` is leaked, but the memory that `t2` points to just prior to the return from  `main` was `free`d

Answer (score 2):

After these 2 lines

```
double *t1 = (double *)calloc(6, sizeof(double));
double *t2 = (double *)calloc(6, sizeof(double));
```

- t1 is the only way to refer to the memory allocated in the first line
- t2 is the only way to refer to the memory allocated in the second line

SO if you want to use and ultimately free those chunks, you need those pointer values somewhere.

So

```
t2=t1;
```

Now loses all access to the second chunk. You have no way to refer to it.
There is nothing 'special' about 't1' and 't2' you can do:

```
 double * foo = t1;
 double * bar = t2;
 t2 = t1;
 t1 = NULL;
```

or whatever you like with them, because now you have those values stored in 'foo' and 'bar'. You just have to store those pointer values somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. `foo` and `bar` will store the original positions of memory. t2 and  t1 are just extra keys to memory space. We still have access to memory even t2 and t1 are messed up later on.